# Does a dense subspace of test functions induce the (weak-$\ast$) topology on the space of distributions?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Suppose $E$ is a dense subspace of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is it true that the topology on $\mathcal{S}’(\mathbb{R}^n)$ induced by the linear functionals $u\mapsto u(\phi)$, $\phi\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ coincides with the usual weak-$\ast$ topology on $\mathcal{S}’(\mathbb{R}^n)$? What about $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\mathcal{D}’(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

The specific problem that I have in mind is this. Let $(u_j)_j$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{S}’(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Suppose we can show that $u_j(\phi)\rightarrow 0 $ as $j\rightarrow\infty$ for all $\phi$ that can be factorized as $$\phi(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) = \phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)\cdots\phi_n(x_n)$$ where $\phi_1, \phi_2, \cdots, \phi_n\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Does it then follow that $u_j\rightarrow 0 $ in $\mathcal{S}’(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. By (IV.1.2) in [1], there is a one-to-one correspondence between "weak-topologies"  and "dual spaces".

In other words, if $\phi$ lies in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)\setminus E$,  then the evaluation at $\phi$, namely the
functional
$$
  u\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)\mapsto  u(\varphi )\in \mathbb R
  $$
is **not** continuous with respect to the topology described in the question, and hence that topology is not the same
as the weak-$*$ topology.

[1] *Schaefer, Helmut H.; Wolff, M. P.*, Topological vector spaces., Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 3. New York, NY: Springer. vi, 346 p. (1999). [ZBL0983.46002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0983.46002).

Comment: On the other hand, on *equicontinuous* subsets of the dual $X'$ of a locally convex space, the weak$^*$ topology $\sigma(X',X)$ coincides with every coarser Hausdorff topology (because of compactness à la Alaoglu).